# forcing getopt_long() to match complete argument

Tags: c, getopt-long

I'm using dashes to handle large option names, such as:

- --load-ptest
- --load-program

Both of these options take no arguments for simplicity.

Here's the code snippet I'm using as an example:

```
enum FLAGS{
    LOAD_PTEST_FLAG,
    LOAD_PROGRAM_FLAG
};

static struct option long_options[] = {
    {"load-program", no_argument, 0, LOAD_PROGRAM_FLAG},
    {"load-ptest", no_argument, 0, LOAD_PTEST_FLAG},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

while((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
    case LOAD_PTEST_FLAG:
        load_ptest = 1;
        break;
    case LOAD_PROG_THRU_GLI_FLAG:
        load_program = 1;
        break;
    case '?':
        print_help();
        break;
}
```

However, I've noticed that when running this code, getopt_long() doesn't seem to be checking the complete option name.
Running `./a.out --load-pt` results with variable `load_ptest` set,
while running `./a.out --load-pr` results with variable `load_program` set.
Additionaly, running `./a.out --load-p` results with:

```
option '--load-p' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--load-program' '--load-ptest'
```

I'm wondering why getopt_long() is only matching partially.
Is there any way to make it strictly check for a full match of the option name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182041/turn-off-abbreviation-in-getopt-long-optarg-h