# bash long options weird behavior - just for curiosity

Tags: bash, getopts

I have this bash script, which does something after getting parameters. What I´m curious about is why it also accepts "--env, --envi, ..." when I just specified "environment" as valid option.
Can I somehow lower its tolerance to only accept the whole word?

```
.......

args=$(getopt -a -o e: --long 'help,environment:' -- "$@")

if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then
  usage
fi

eval set -- ${args}

while :
do
  case $1 in
    -e | --environment)
         {
         case $2 in
                 PROD) CHECK_FILE=${NFS_MOUNT_PROD}/${FILE_MONITORING}; break ;;
                 INT) CHECK_FILE=${NFS_MOUNT_INT}/${FILE_MONITORING}; break ;;
                 *) usage; exit1;;
         esac
         }
         shift 2  ;;
    --help) usage                            ; shift   ;;
    # -- means the end of the arguments; drop this, and break out of the while loop
    --) shift; break ;;
    *) >&2 echo Unsupported option: $1
       usage ;;
  esac
done

.......
```

Thanks guys and greetings,

JP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off abbreviation in getopt\_long (getopt.h)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182041/turn-off-abbreviation-in-getopt-long-getopt-h)

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the man page for [getopt](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html#:%7E:text=Long%20options%20may%20be%20abbreviated%2C%20as%20long%20as%20the%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20abbreviation%20is%20not%20ambiguous) (or `man getopt`) and found the following:

> Long options may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is not ambiguous.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options) is a decent answer thread on using getopt vs getops.